# MVC .Net Front End and Back End

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am very new to .Net and MVC specifically.  I am building a site which will need a front end and a back end (admin site).  I created a project and am developing the front end, now how do I start a back end for this site?  Do I need to create a new solution?  (what exactly is a "solution"?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason why you wouldn't use the same project for both sites, unless the admin area is to be hosted on a different domain. If you do share the project, you'll probably want to place configure the admin controllers into a separate [ASP.NET MVC Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx).

A "solution" is a group of projects. For example, a solution might contain a web application project, a console application project, and a few shared class library projects.

Answer (score 1):

Paul,

In Visual Studio, a "Solution" can contain one or more "projects". A project (for the most part) an the application you are trying to create. In your case an ASP.NET MVC "project".

If you're building an ASP.NET MVC application, then your front and backend could (and probably should) be the same project. The url that gives you access to your "admin" pages is different from the site of the site (most likely) but the project is really the same.

Unless the domain for the admin site will be different there is no need to develop the admin site as a different ASP.NET MVC project.

If this doesn't answer your question, please let us know what you have in mind as regards the urls of the two "ends" (front and back ends).